# devenv /deploy build but doesn't publish

Tags: visual-studio, winforms

I have to publish a project where we use Winform and vb and when i run the command

`devenv myproject.vbproj /deploy`

The command will build my project but it dosen't publish my solution.

did somenone knox how to fix that ?

PS: I tried to use the vsLaunchDevCmd to run it and it doesn't work too and i also tried to set the configuration to Release.

Comment: please refer to the link [/Deploy (devenv.exe)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/deploy-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) to use command to publish the project. There is a example in the link.

Comment: I already use this command but it's just building my project but the devenv command dosen't pulish it. I don't knwo why

Comment: Based on my further test, I also reproduce your problem. Therefore, you can report a problem about visual studio in [Developer Community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67042140/showing-a-build-error-in-vb-net-while-making-a-calculator)